# How to convert 2009-09-18 to 18th Sept in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

want to know How to convert 2009-09-18 to 18th Sept in xslt?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a pure XSLT 1.0 solution which assumes valid input:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <newdate>
        <xsl:call-template name="convertdate">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="date"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </newdate>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="convertdate">   
    <xsl:param name="date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="day">
        <xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(substring-after($date,'-'), '-'))"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="suffix">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$day = '1'">st</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($day, string-length($day), 1) = '1' and not(starts-with($day, '1'))">st</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($day, string-length($day), 1) = '2' and not(starts-with($day, '1'))">nd</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($day, string-length($day), 1) = '3' and not(starts-with($day, '1'))">rd</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>th</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="mo">
        <xsl:value-of select="number(substring-before(substring-after($date,'-'), '-'))"/>
    </xsl:variable>     

    <xsl:variable name="month">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 1">Jan</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 2">Feb</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 3">Mar</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 4">Apr</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 5">May</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 6">Jun</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 7">Jul</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 8">Aug</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 9">Sept</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 10">Oct</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 11">Nov</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$mo = 12">Dec</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$day"/><xsl:value-of select="$suffix"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="$month"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nice, +1. :) And using non-breaking spaces is actually also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

EXSLT has some extension functions for converting date strings, see:
http://exslt.org/date/index.html

With a little luck your XSLT processor supports these natively, otherwise most of the date functions have a plain XSLT 1.0 implementation you can include

Answer (score 0):

what language is your backend in?

If it's PHP it's easy to format DATETIME strings with the date() function: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You can format the date before passing it off into XML form.

Comment: yeah, thats true and the easy/best solution.but what if I have to handle it through xslt

Answer (score 0):

Using named template with a big `<xsl:choose>` sounds like an appropriate solution here. The tricky part is month name, the rest is pretty trivial, right? Of course you don't *have* to separate it to the named template.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template name="friendly-date">
  <xsl:param name="datestring" select="'yyyy-mm-dd'" />

  <xsl:variable name="y" select="number(substring-before($datestring, '-'))" />
  <xsl:variable name="r" select="number(substring-after($datestring, '-'))" />
  <xsl:variable name="m" select="number(substring-before($r, '-'))" />
  <xsl:variable name="d" select="number(substring-after($r, '-'))" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="
      $y &gt;= 1970 and $y &lt;= 9999
      and
      $m &gt;= 1 and $m &lt;= 12
      and
      $d &gt;= 1 and $m &lt;= 31
    ">
      <xsl:value-of select="$d" />
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$m = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="'Jan'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- ... insert missing ... -->
        <xsl:when test="$m = 12">
          <xsl:value-of select="'Dec'" />
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$y" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$datestring" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Beware that this will not check for impossible dates. It depends on your input if that can become a problem or not.

Apart from that, it does not do international date formats. For less ad-hoc solutions, I recommend a look at EXSLT, like the other do.